# Segmentation fault using cvtps2dq and cvttps2dq

Tags: assembly

Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit. GNU as.

```
.section .data

value1:

    .float 1.25 , 124.79 , 200.0 , -312.5

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:

    nop

    cvtps2dq  value1 , %xmm0
    cvttps2dq value1 , %xmm1

    movl $1 , %eax
    movl $0 , %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Running the program results in a segmentation fault:

```
~/scratch $ as --64 test.s -o test.o && ld test.o -o test -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lc
~/scratch $ ./test
Segmentation fault
~/scratch $
```

Funny thing is, if I compile the program with only one of these two lines (either one):

```
cvtps2dq  value1 , %xmm0
cvttps2dq value1 , %xmm1
```

it runs fine.

Any suggestions?

By the way, this example is based on one from the book "Professional Assembly Language" by Richard Blum. The examples are written for 32-bit Linux and I've had to do some converting accordingly. So maybe it's a 32/64 bit thing. :-)

Thanks!

Ed

Comment: This doesn't crash for me.  Of course it doesn't do much of anything visible.  You can simplify your link to just `ld test.o -o test`.  Beware of naming executables "test": there is a /bin/test (on Linux /usr/bin/test) which will eventually surprise you if your own program has the same name.

Comment: Hi Ben. If I build via `as --64 test.s -o test.o && ld test.o -o test` then it works.

Comment: This also works: `as --64 test.s -o test.o && ld test.o -o test -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

Comment: But this (from the original question) `as --64 test.s -o test.o && ld test.o -o test -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lc` results in a program that segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify alignment and memory operands to SSE2 opcodes have a 16-byte alignment requirement. That might be screwing you. For GNU AS, try adding `.align 4` before `value1:` (in GNU AS on x86, "align 4" means "make sure the bottom 4 bits of the address are zero", not "align the address to a multiple of 4").

Also, what instruction do you get the segfault on? The actual issue might be something unrelated.

Comment: Hi Fabian. The `.align 4` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: According to gdb, the segfault happens at `cvtps2dq  value1 , %xmm0`.

Comment: @dharmatech: Try `.align 16` instead of `.align 4`.